# $.post doesnt work when datatype declared

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I noticed that the following code doesn't work. When I remove `, "json");` at the end of it, it works but i just get failure. I followed it to jquery spec on the site. Any idea why the `$.post` method won't work/enter?

The reason i know it wont enter $.post is because `alert(form.serialize());` doesnt get called.

In my PHP i am returning the following when it posts:

```
        $arr = array('status' => 'SUCCESS');

        echo json_encode($arr);
         exit();
```

This is my ajax below:

```
var form = $('#lines');
        $.post('', form.serialize(), function(json) {
            alert(form.serialize());

            if(json.status === 'SUCCESS') {
                alert(json);
                console.log('success');
            } else {
                alert(json);
                console.log('failure');
            }
        }, "json");
```

If I remove the json part at the end, it just returns the entire HTML of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is probably not json. If you remove `,"json"`, it works but post return string datas so your code can't work (json.status on string won't work). If you put `,"json"`, then it won't probably work if return is not proper json.

What you can do : leave "json" in the end, as this is what you want, add `console.data(json) ;` and `console.data(typeof json) ;` just at start of your success function.

Forget about alert, first it stop your script, and it's not as precise as console. Use console when you can.

I can suggest you to write it like this to make it more readable :

```
 console.log('form.serialize()',form.serialize()) ;

    var post = $.ajax({
        method : 'POST',
        url : '',
        data : form.serialize(),
        dataType : "json"
    });

    post.done(function(json){

        console.log('success',json) ;
        console.log('typeof json',typeof json) ;

        if(json.status === 'SUCCESS') {
            console.log('success');
        } else {
            console.log('failure');
        }

    }) ;

    post.fail(function(data){
        console.log('fail',data) ;
        alert('post fail') ;
    }) ;
```

Here is my complete php file `index.php`. Structure should looks like your one. Just note the top part where i make sure than when i have post data, i echo only the json and returns, so nothing else is sent (like your exit).

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['name']) )
    {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'SUCCESS')) ;
        return false ;
    }
?>

<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="button" />
</form>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    jQuery('input[type="button"]').on('click',function(){

        var form = jQuery(this).closest('form') ;

        console.log('form.serialize()',form.serialize()) ;

        var post = $.ajax({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '',
            data : form.serialize(),
            dataType : "json"
        });

        post.done(function(json){

            console.log('success',json) ;
            console.log('typeof json',typeof json) ;

            if(json.status === 'SUCCESS') {
                console.log('success');
            } else {
                console.log('failure');
            }

        }) ;

        post.fail(function(data){
            console.log(this) ; 
            console.log('fail',data) ;
            alert('post fail') ;
        }) ;
    }) ;

</script>
```

Comment: FYI: It just returns object object if i remove the json part

Comment: What returns object object ? alert(json) ? That's why you need to use console instead of alert, it's more detailled and you'll see the complete object. Have you tried with the code below ? (i've edited it it had some mistakes)

Comment: Yea im just getting fail right now im trying to check my php end.

Comment: after "fail" in console you should have some message ? you're sure it calls your php file ? url:'' means you're calling the index.php in same folder, are you sure that's where your php is ?

Comment: Well im calling the ajax from the same file yea.

Comment: Correct! I am doing this all in the same index.php file

Comment: In console the responsetext just prints the entire html of the website

Comment: Okay so the problem is probably on the php side : when you post, it does not enter well the part where you write json_encode(...) and returns. What yo do in this file ? if ( isset($_POST['...']) of something like this ? Sure this code is in top of your file to make sure you don't echo anything else ? I've edited my answer with my php file test wich works for me.

Comment: If your index.php is not too big you can write it complete.

Comment: I will try to edit it give me a bit! This is genuinely how mine is setup too but i must have some other issue, I know for a fact now its not enterting the isset

Comment: Eventually you should consider to send your post to a different file, like url : 'post.php', so it's easier to debug too. As i can see now the problem is clearly that your php file does not send only json_encode(..) so the problem is there.

Comment: Defintely you are right, I see its not entering the isset statement, I am sending multiple fields in a form, could that be the reason?

Comment: I don't think so. Can you add your complete php code ? You probably just have a wrong test at start of your index.php who does not enter in your condition.

Comment: Ok i figured it out, its because I didnt have `return false ;` after the json_encode. But now the issue is I cant do anything after that.

Comment: After what ? After return false ? that's exactly the meaning of a return. Can you provide you whole php code ?

Comment: Sure here is another example close to my code.

If i have echo something before the return i get an error.

`<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['name']) )
    {
 
   echo "Hello good sir!";

        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'SUCCESS')) ;
  
  
        return false ;
  
  

    }
?>`

Comment: Nothing is changed same as what you have besides the php portion but if i do anything before return or before echo json_encode i get an error and it doesnt echo hello good sir as well.

Comment: When your ajax call your index.php, index.php is supposed to echo one and only thing : a json string. Anything else will cause an error as your ajax expect json as return. I don't get exactly what you want to do before json_encode and return ? Are you sure what you want to do do not echo anything ? If yes you will see it in console : `console.log('json',json);` will display the whole return : what does it show in your console ?

Comment: Well i wanted to run some code before posting SUCCESS such as save a file to the server and then redirect to that file. But now i cant do anything before and after that json_encode. I was going to redirect in the success portion of the ajax call FYI.

Comment: Look at the console, tell me what you have on the line "json"

Comment: Do you have an alert fail ? If yes, can you replace `console.log('fail',data) ;` by `console.log('fail',data.responseText) ;` and tell me what you have in console ?

Comment: If i put `echo json_encode(array('status' => 'SUCCESS')) ; return false ;` at the top I get success, if i put it at the bottom after the save file i get `form.serialize() name=68568
index.php:73 fail Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}`

Comment: What if i make a if statement checking if the file saves and then echo it?

Comment: Of course ! if you put in in the end of the file, then everything else will be echo before "SUCCESS", so instead of return only a json string, your ajax call return the whole html code included in index.php. You have to put your json_encode at start of the file !

Comment: Got it! So is there any way to still do the save file before that?

Comment: Show me your whole php code, there's something wrong in what you do... When your ajax send POST to index.php, index should ONLY return json string, that's all.
1) give me the whole index.php or 2) replace console.log('fail',data) ; by console.log('fail',data.responseText) ; and tell me what you have in console ?

Comment: You can do what you want before json_encode, as long as it does not echo anything.

Comment: Styll try to replace `console.log('fail',data) ;` by `console.log('fail',data.responseText) ;` : it will shhow in console the string return by your ajax call, so you will easily see what is echo before or after your json_encode and make your code fail

Comment: Cool ! Got it! Thanks! Yea i had a white space actually LOL

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the headers in your php code and tell jQuery that a "json" response is on the way.. here is the correct php code

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$arr = array('status' => 'SUCCESS');
echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
```

notice the line that sends json headers,  try it now and it'll work